# Application for phonegap with remote database

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I made an application based on phone gap 2.9.1 android application with local database
with transaction and create query. but now i want to make remote database for this application so that i can use it from anywhere with same database. Can anyone help me? please..

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Make a webservice. connect through it using ajax and parse json

**Edited**

I tried something like this (this is not web service though)
below is made from ASP.Net

```
    [AllowCrossSiteJson]
    public JsonResult AddPerson(Person person)
    {
           //Get Data here 
           return Json(*put something here*);
    }
```

and called it in my javascript

```
       function saveData(person) {
            var json = $.toJSON(person); //converts person object to json
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://somedomain.com/Ajax/AddPerson",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: json,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("ok");
                }
            });
        }
```

**Edited Part 2**

You can do the same in PHP

Comment: Thanks. can you give me example for this. i am very new in phonegap. or tell me in which i have to make web service?? means can i make it in .net?? will it work??

Comment: is there any other option than making web service?? I know this option but i don't know how to make this for android application??

Comment: On my end, I used ASP.Net to call my functions to manipulate my data from windows azure.

Comment: Please see my edit above, and if it is somewhat clears what you ask, please mark this as asnwer..

Comment: Thanks.. But actually still i am not getting where to write the asp.net code while i am making application in eclipse for android.

Comment: Do you know about web service for android application.. I worked with web service but in .net only and called also in .net project. I really don't know about android in eclipse. Please help me..

Comment: Or you could just do something like this..
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-phonegap-get-started/

Comment: By the way, I only use Windows Azure for my cloud database (I'm assuming that you are talking about cloud database)

Comment: what i want to do is the database should be on server like we r doing in asp.net. means what the web site can run from any where the changes in database should be done in same database only. like this i want to do in phonegap android app. because in this we make database using code so it made database on runtime so when we run it creates new database evrytime. i don't want to do this.. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. Now I get you. you need to publish the website. (If it is in dot net) you could just follow the above sample code. and in your phonegap javascript, you just need an ajax call to JsonResult in ASP.Net, you can get the information directly from the database where ASP.Net is fetching its data.

Comment: Here's the scenario, I published my site named example.com and then I have a controller named Ajax. Within my Ajax controller, I have AddPerson JsonResult (or even a void function), you just need to access that controller through an external site (it should be published). Now, how do we call controllers, like this "http://example.com/Ajax/Addperson" right? and then fulfill the needed parameters on your ajax call.

Comment: u gave example is i think in mvc.. i want to do in phonegap then what i have to do ?? because i think there is no controller. am i right??? sorry for such question but this is my first remote phonegap application.. Thanks..

Comment: You need to publish your asp.net mvc site. and in your phonegap application, you need to call it through ajax. just like my example above.

Comment: I want to know that how can i make database such a way that can created only once and while i run application the changes will done in same database which is already created. That's all i want to know and yes using phonegap android app.

Comment: I am guessing we're not on the same page. You have a website (ASP.Net Website) and you would want to connect its database to your Phonegap application. Am I right?

Comment: function LoginButton_onclick() {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",   
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",   
dataType: "json",
url:"http://localhost:44241/WebService1.asmx/helloworld",
data: '{}',
success: function(msg) {
alert("ok");
},
error: function(msg) {
alert("Error");
}
});
}
This goes into error can u help me what is wrong in this for passing web sevice url to json for phonegap app.Thanks

Comment: is the phone and your asp.net site connected? meaning on the same network?

Comment: yes, it is. is there any problem if i test in phonegap emulator? means would localhost web service work on emulator? If not please give another solution to test. Thanx

Comment: Can you ping the IP of your emulator?